# bower_components not being included in yo angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm using the latest yo angular generator to build an angular based app. I've `bower install --save` the bower_component 'angular-iscroll' which installed its dependency 'iscroll'

However, when trying to compile my project the 'iscroll' component doesn't get injected into the build.

How do I configure my project to include the component into the build?

I'm turning to a reference bug at https://github.com/mtr/angular-iscroll/issues/16

but the thing is I AM including the bower in my bower.json file but during the `build` process it keeps getting overlooked why is *grunt* not including the file?

Comment: Please precise *"the 'scroll' component doesn't get injected into the build"*

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos in the gruntfile.js the project's bower_components are usually injected into the html code.....the only bower_component being left out is the 'iscroll' bower_component.

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos the angular-iscroll is being added just not the 'iscroll'. I manually try to include into the index.html file but it gets overwritten once i update any html